Expo CheckBox doesn't react to touch on iOS but works on the web
In my Expo v.52 application, I had a SectionList with several CheckBoxes. When these CheckBoxes are inside a SectionList or FlatList component, they don't react to touch input on iOS, but they do work on the web.

I tried to log the press, but there was no output.

Then I moved the checkbox outside of the SectionList, and it worked there.

Then I migrated to expo-checkbox because I thought it could be a problem with the component I made myself.

I read that it could be due to some issues with the SectionList component, then I migrated to FlatList.


Code example:
<Checkbox        
    value={!!checkedItems["someID"]}       
    onValueChange={() => toggleCheckbox("SomeID")}
    color={!!checkedItems["someID"] ? '#4630EB' : undefined}
/>

